# store data locally when no network access in android

Tags: android, sdk, storage, local

I want to send data in my database using httppostrequest.But when there is no network access how to store data locally and when my application receives network post it to server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a database might be a good solution.  [The notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) is a decent introduction to programming with databases in an Android app.

Also, it's worth spending the time necessary to read and become familiar with the topics covered in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. ,but my database is online ,i want to store it locally only for a short period when there is no network,

Comment: The storage in the local database could be used for just "a short period when there is no network".  There's no reason why the data you might put there for temporary storage must remain there for longer durations.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to check for connection:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();

}
```

On storing data to SQLite check this tutorial:

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-simple-but-persistent-data-storage/

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. ,but my database is online ,i want to store it locally only for a short period when there is no network

Comment: Just make a SQlite database and treat it like a cache folder. Use the code check to determine if you can make a web call or when you have to revert to your cache ( DB )

Answer (score 0):

I approve Mark Mooibroek response  and advise to use some DB helper instead of raw SQLite, as it needs a lot of boilerplate code.
Last time I was glad with using [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) database library. It's faster than SQLite in terms of both efficiency and coding time.